# Disabling a button based on value in a UITextField only works once (RxSwift)

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm trying to get to grips with `RxCocoa` and have experienced an unusual bug relating to some dynamic UI behaviour I'm trying to implement.

I have a `UITextField` that's used for user input. The button which adds the input to a Realm database is bound to an `RxSwift` Action. This works absolutely fine.

Initially, I disabled the button until there was text of at least 1 character in length in the `UITextField` - the code of this works fine. The bug in my code arose when I then added a subscription to the Action's executionObservables parameter that should clear the UITextField after the button is pressed.

Expected behaviour:

- No text (initial state) > button disabled
- Text entered > button enabled
- Text entered and button pressed > text field cleared and button disabled

Actual behaviour:

- No text  (initial state) > button disabled
- Text entered > button enabled
- Text entered and button pressed > text field cleared BUT button remains enabled

Adding debug() indicates that the binding to the UITextField that disables the button is disposed but I can't figure out why as the UIViewController and its associated view model should still be in scope. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Code snippet:

```
func bindViewModel() {
    // populate table
    viewModel.output.sectionedObservations
        .drive(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    // only allow enable button when there is text in the textfield
    observationTextField.rx.text
        .debug()
        .map { $0!.count > 0 }
        .bind(to: addObservationButton.rx.isEnabled)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

// clear textfield once Action triggered by button press has completed
viewModel.addObservation.executionObservables
    .subscribe({ [unowned self] _ in
        self.observationTextField.rx.text.onNext("")
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)

// add Observation to Realm using Action provided by the view model
addObservationButton.rx.tap
    .withLatestFrom(observationTextField.rx.text.orEmpty)
    .take(1)
    .bind(to: viewModel.addObservation.inputs)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: Aside from you question - this `$0!.count > 0` is a crash waiting to happen. Replace it with a safe operation like . `($0?.count ?? 0) > 0`

Comment: I'm aware but thanks for highlighting. This was quick, experimental code and definitely needs refactoring to take care of the dreaded optional!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you ultimately need the viewModel to tell the `observationTextField` what its value should be. I got into the habit of creating a `Driver` for every output of the viewModel, then bind that to your textfield. Use that to replace your `viewModel.addObservation.executionObservables`

Comment: I do need to programatically amend the contents of the UITextField but only to erase it so I wouldn't have thought that I need a direct input from the view model. Using executionObservables ensures that the Action has been performed correctly and, as the amendment is to set the .text property to "", I thought a simple approach was best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a little misunderstanding about how `ControlProperty` trait behaves. Let's take a look at specific behavior which is [Programmatic value changes won't be reported](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/Traits/ControlProperty.swift#L22)

This Observable `observationTextField.rx.text` after subscription will not emit event for both:

`self.observationTextField.rx.text.onNext("")`

or

`self.observationTextField.text = ""`

I have 2 suggestion for your code:

1) Do the job manually:

```swift
viewModel.addObservation.executionObservables
    .subscribe({ [unowned self] _ in
        self.observationTextField = ""
        self.addObservationButton.isEnabled = false
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

2) Add one more Observable and subscription:

```swift
//a
    viewModel.addObservation.executionObservables
      .map { _ in return "" }
      .bind(to: observationTextField.rx.text)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    viewModel.addObservation.executionObservables
      .map { _ in return false }
      .bind(to: addObservationButton.rx.isEnabled)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

```swift
//b
    let executionObservables = viewModel.addObservation
      .executionObservables
      .share()

    executionObservables
      .map { _ in return "" }
      .bind(to: observationTextField.rx.text)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    executionObservables
      .map { _ in return false }
      .bind(to: addObservationButton.rx.isEnabled)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Not sure how `Action` is implemented, to prevent job done twice maybe you have to share resources.

Comment: Thanks for the steer Sergey. That did the trick and now I understand what I did wrong (and hopefully make that mistake again!)

Comment: Quick thought: is .do not preferred to .subscribe(onNext:) in this context as we're performing a UI side effect rather than altering the elements within the stream? The manual update of the UI is more compact than the other versions (even with the extra line) and just as expressive. I've now got the expected behaviour. Thanks again

Comment: as for me I'm ok with both:

```swift
    viewModel.addObservation.executionObservables
      .do(onNext: {  _ in
        self.observationTextField = ""
        self.addObservationButton.isEnabled = false
      })
      .subscribe()
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and

```swift
viewModel.addObservation.executionObservables
    .subscribe({ [unowned self] _ in
        self.observationTextField = ""
        self.addObservationButton.isEnabled = false
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Personally I prefer code in subscribe closure.